# Abstract algebra-normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found the following problem is quite hard for me, and I tried a lot but something I can't bring in my mind.
Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ ($G$ can be finte or infinite) such that $[G:K]=m$. If $n$ is a positive integer such that $gcd(m,n)=1$, then show $K$ contains all elements of order $n$ in $G$.

I start by assuming that there exists an element of order $n$ which is outside $K$, then tried for getting a contradiction. But the group isn't provided finite,so I can't reach too far. Kindly provide me some hints.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to typeset your questions.

Comment: Your assumptions show that both $(aK)^m = K$ and $(aK)^n=K$ where $a$ has order $n$.  Can the order of $aK$ be $n$?

Comment: can u plz explain why (aK)m=K

Comment: got it.since order of G/K is m so that follows and the problem is done for finite case.thank you

Comment: oho sorry for both cases.